# Building VB assembly in C# using VBCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource but cannot access functions inside VB code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dynamic, code-generation

The VB code:

```
Public Module OnlyModule
    Public Sub OnlyFunction()
        'do stuff
    End Sub
End Module
```

the C# code:

```
    Assembly vbAssembly = BuildAssembly(vbCode); //wrapper function, but returns valid, compiled vb assembly
    Module module = vbAssembly.GetModules()[0];
    MethodInfo method = module.GetMethods()[0]; //returns 0 methods!!
    method.Invoke(null, null);
```

As you can see, there's only one module, and only one function in it, so why doesn't my call to GetMethods() work?  I'm not totally familiar with VB, but it should be a static method, and I think it's written the proper way as just a sub inside a module.

Comment: 'Shared' is VB.Net's 'static'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to use GetType() rather than GetModule():

```
Type type = vbAssembly.GetType("OnlyModule");
Method method = type.GetMethods()[0];
```

Works :)